# How do I split a string at an occurrence of a character in shell using set and awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I am using an embedded version of shell. And I need to split a string using set and awk?

NO BASH PLEASE.

How do I do this?

The following script is not complete and spells out wrong output.

```
#!/bin/sh

string="1:2"

set -- $(echo $string | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
echo "1: $1"
echo "2: $2"
```

Here is the output:

```
1: 2
2:
```

Answer (score 0):

If `:` is the delimiter and using `awk` is not mandatory, `tr` can get the job done.

```
$ string="1:2"
$ set -- $(echo $string | tr ':' ' ');
$ echo "1: $1"
1: 1
$ echo "2: $2"
2: 2
$ _
```